# Planar disk axisymmetric

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I'm trying to recreate this image:
[image: DisksWithCylindricalAxisAxisymmetric]

The figure is representing an axisymmetric representation (cylindrical coordinate system) of 2 planar coils of wire. I am wanting to add some intuition to the reader, showing them that we represent the problem on the plane, but actually it is a "3d" model.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=7pt]{standalone}

%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4.5]

    \tikzset{zxplane/.style={canvas is zx plane at y=#1,very thin}}
    \tikzset{yxplane/.style={canvas is yx plane at z=#1,very thin}}

    % Coil 1
    \begin{scope}[zxplane=-0.1] % Reflection
        \draw[fill=blue!40,opacity=0.8,even odd rule] (0,0) circle (0.1) (0,0) circle (0.42);
    \end{scope}

    % Coil 2
    \begin{scope}[zxplane=0.175] % Secondary
        \draw[fill=green!40,opacity=0.8,even odd rule] (0,0) circle (0.228) (0,0) circle (0.428);
    \end{scope}

    % Plane
    \draw [fill=black, opacity=0.2] (0,-0.5) rectangle (0.5, 0.5);
    \draw [dashed] (0, -0.5) -- (0, 0.5);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which currently looks like this:

[image: MWE]

I don't know how to make the plane break the loops. Any help would be much appreciated. Also the coils look lopsided, would be nice to have them straight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! You are already close. I introduce 3d orthographic coordinates by loading `tikz-3dplot` and also draw things in the order: half-coils in the back, plane and finally half-coils in the foreground.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=4.5,
xyplane/.style={canvas is xy plane at z=#1,very thin}]
%     \tikzset{zxplane/.style={canvas is zx plane at y=#1,very thin}}
%     \tikzset{yxplane/.style={canvas is yx plane at z=#1,very thin}}

    % Coil 1 in the back
    \begin{scope}[xyplane=-0.1] % Reflection
        \clip(-0.5,0) rectangle (0.5,1);
        \draw[fill=blue!40,opacity=0.8,even odd rule] (0,0) circle (0.1) (0,0) circle (0.42);
    \end{scope}

    % Coil 2 in the back
    \begin{scope}[xyplane=0.175] % Secondary
        \clip(-0.5,0) rectangle (0.5,1);
        \draw[fill=green!40,opacity=0.8,even odd rule] (0,0) circle (0.228) (0,0) circle (0.428);
    \end{scope}

    % Plane
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
    \draw [fill=black, opacity=0.2] (0,-0.5) rectangle (0.5, 0.5);
    \draw [dashed] (0, -0.5) -- (0, 0.5);
    \end{scope}

    % Coil 1 in the front
    \begin{scope}[xyplane=-0.1] % Reflection
        \clip(-0.5,0) rectangle (0.5,-1);
        \draw[fill=blue!40,opacity=0.8,even odd rule] (0,0) circle (0.1) (0,0) circle (0.42);
    \end{scope}

    % Coil 2 in the front
    \begin{scope}[xyplane=0.175] % Secondary
        \clip(-0.5,0) rectangle (0.5,-1);
        \draw[fill=green!40,opacity=0.8,even odd rule] (0,0) circle (0.228) (0,0) circle (0.428);
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can play with the view angles, which are set by `\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{0}`.